# Is this a hacked Virizion?

Tags: pokemon-sword-shield

I received this Virizion through a surprise trade:

[image: Virizion's summary page]

- When it arrived it had the [Pokérus](https://bulbapedia.bulbagarden.net/wiki/Pok%C3%A9rus) virus.
- It's a shiny.

I thought those were two very rare combos to have.

Is this a hacked Virizion?

Comment: It's name is "The Cheese" in french, but it comes from Germany... it's shiny and it it has perfect IV's, I'd bet on it being hacked. Who would wonder trade away a shiny like that?

Comment: @hammythepig perfect IV's? How can you tell?

Comment: Sorry, typo, "it it" should be "if it". You can tell with the [judge function](https://ca.ign.com/wikis/pokemon-sword-shield/How_to_Unlock_the_IV_Checker_in_Pokemon_Sword_and_Shield_-_Individual_Values) if you have it unlocked.

Answer (score 15):

It doesn't necessarily have to be a hacked one. The chances of getting a shiny legendary are not high, but you can add Pokerus very easily after that, by letting the virus [spread itself](https://bulbapedia.bulbagarden.net/wiki/Pok%C3%A9rus#Infection):

> As long as the Pokémon is infected with the Pokérus, it can spread the virus to other Pokémon in the player's party

Because you obtained it through a surprise trade, it hasn't got any illegal moves or stats, and there is no way to know for sure if it was hacked or not. You could check out [this question](https://gaming.stackexchange.com/q/161431/80141) to get an idea how to check if it's hacked or not.

Comment: I once got a lv100 Gastly with perfect IVs with very competitive move set (albeit all legal moves), Pokérus, with Master Ball as it's held item. Summary also had conflicting information hatch dates: "Hatched from an egg that was found on 01/04/2020" and "It hatched on 01/01/2000 while at the Energy Plant". So there are some ways to identify obviously hacked Pokemon :)

Comment: Wondercricket, you can hatch an egg on a different system to the one where the egg was obtained (or just change the system clock between obtaining the egg and hatching it). So it's not definitive evidence it was hacked (although it definitely was).

Comment: @Wondercricket That could actually be legit. RNG abuse allows you to fairly easily get perfect IVs, but usually involves setting your system date to odd values. After RNGing an egg people would often hatch in specific locations and at specific dates to look cool, and then if you were to clone a Pokémon you'd probably give it a nice item to hold (and likely get some good egg moves on it). Boosting it to level 100 before cloning would be a little odd, though; and if you're going to RNG perfect IVs, may as well RNG shininess too!

Comment: The answer in the question you linked is old and outdated :( does not work

Answer (score 5):

The fact that it is caught in a Master Ball, would actually speak against it being hacked.
Most Pokemon of the fifth generation can actually be caught shiny. Including Virizion.

Pokerus spreads fairly quickly as well. You just need to have the pokemon you want to infect be next to an already infected pokemon in your team for one or two battles.

You can never be sure about Pokemons being hacked or not while surprise trading, but if the pokemon does not arrive in an unusual ball, or has perfect IV's while also being shiny and/or legendary you can usually assume that it is caught legit.

In your case, if you got the IV Checker and it does not show the IV's to be the best in every category, I would presume it to not being hacked.

Comment: What a shame to trade such an Pokemon away. I would never trade my first caught shiny legendary... Nor my second one. Especially since you can make them all battle ready with bottle caps nowadays.

Comment: If it isn't hacked it is almost certainly cloned, it's very common for people to clone Pokemon and give them away.